# How to create a working user account on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

A few days ago I created a new user account on my Windows 7 HP. When I tried to use it, however, I got the following popup:

> The User Profile Service service failed the login. 
>   User account cannot be loaded.

What settings should I change on my computer in order to be able to create a working user account?

Comment: Try this article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947215 or please add additional information to your post on how you added the new user account.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article may be helpful.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947215

Comment: Link-only answers are strongly discouraged. Please provide content **here** and then link elsewhere for more details.